# Highlighting the Text while Speech is Progressing

Tags: java, android, text-to-speech, highlight

I'm developing an App in which I've textview consists of String and two buttons. When I click the speak button, the text gets converted to speech. But I want to **Highlight the word while speech is running**.

Please check the My app screenshot on this below link.
[image]

This is My text to speech initialization:

```
textToSpeech = new TextToSpeech(this, new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {

        @Override
        public void onInit(int status) {

            if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
                result = textToSpeech.setLanguage(Locale.ENGLISH);
                textToSpeech.setOnUtteranceProgressListener(new UtteranceProgressListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onStart(String utteranceId) {
                        Log.d(utteranceId, "TTS start");}

                    @Override
                    public void onDone(String utteranceId) {
                        Log.d(utteranceId, "TTS done");}

                    @Override
                    public void onError(String utteranceId) {
             });
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Feature is not Available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

And other code:

```
private void speak() {
 if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Feature is not Available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        textToSpeech.setPitch(1f);
        textToSpeech.setSpeechRate(0.8f);
        HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_UTTERANCE_ID, "utteranceId");
        textToSpeech.speak(getString(R.string.storytxt), TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, params);

    }
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (textToSpeech != null) {
        textToSpeech.shutdown();
    }
}
```

Till here I didn't get any problem. Now I want to highlight the text. I don't know how to do it.I've searched everywhere still got no lead on this.

I stored the string in String.xml.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For Android API 26 and above AND a TTS engine that supports onRangeStart (in this case, Google TTS):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements TextToSpeech.OnInitListener {

    TextToSpeech tts;

    String sentence = "The Quick Brown Fox Jumps Over The Lazy Dog.";

    TextView textView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
        textView.setText(sentence);
        tts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);

    }

    // TextToSpeech.OnInitListener (for our purposes, the "main method" of this activity)
    public void onInit(int status) {

        tts.setOnUtteranceProgressListener(new UtteranceProgressListener() {

            @Override
            public void onStart(String utteranceId) {
                Log.i("XXX", "utterance started");
            }

            @Override
            public void onDone(String utteranceId) {
                Log.i("XXX", "utterance done");
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(String utteranceId) {
                Log.i("XXX", "utterance error");
            }

            @Override
            public void onRangeStart(String utteranceId,
                                     final int start,
                                     final int end,
                                     int frame) {
                Log.i("XXX", "onRangeStart() ... utteranceId: " + utteranceId + ", start: " + start
                        + ", end: " + end + ", frame: " + frame);

                // onRangeStart (and all UtteranceProgressListener callbacks) do not run on main thread
                // ... so we explicitly manipulate views on the main thread:
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        Spannable textWithHighlights = new SpannableString(sentence);
                        textWithHighlights.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.YELLOW), start, end, Spanned.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
                        textView.setText(textWithHighlights);

                    }
                });

            }

        });

    }

    public void startClicked(View ignored) {

        tts.speak(sentence, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null, "doesn't matter yet");

    }

}
```

// -------------------------------------------------------------------

Android API 25 and below:

In theory, the most intuitive way of accomplish this would be to:

`1)` Break the string into **pieces**

`2)` Detect when each piece has been/is being spoken

`3)` **Highlight** that piece accordingly

However, unfortunately, when using the Android TextToSpeech class where the speech output is generated in real-time, the smallest unit of speech that you are able to precisely detect the progress of (using UtteranceProgressListener) is an *utterance* (whatever string you decided to send to the TTS) -- not necessarily a *word.*

There is no mechanism whereby you can simply send a multi-word string as an utterance, and then somehow detect exactly when each word has been spoken.

Therefore, in order to (easily) highlight each word in order, you would have to either:

`A)` Send each word to the TTS individually as a single utterance (but this will cause disjointed pronunciation), or

`B)` Highlight sentence-by-sentence instead, sending each sentence as an utterance (easiest method, but not your desired behaviour).

If you really insist on achieving a word-by-word highlighting effect, the only way I can think of (using Android `TextToSpeech`) is to use sentence-size utterances, but instead of using speak(), use synthesizeToFile()... and then use a media player or sound player of some sort to play the speech back... somehow approximating the timing of the highlights in terms of where the nth word lies relative to the total audio file length.  So, for example, if the sentence is 10 words long, and the file is 30% complete, then you would highlight the 4th word.  This would be difficult and inexact, but theoretically possible.

There are obviously apps and games that already exist that do this... games like Parappa the Rapper, or karaoke apps, but I think the way they do it is by having pre-recorded/static audio files with markers encoded at exact times that trigger the highlights.  If your text content is always going to be the same, and only in one language, then you could also do this.

However, if the spoken text is user-entered or unknown until runtime, requiring a TTS, then I don't know of any straight-forward solution.

If you decide on one of these more narrowed-down approaches, then I would suggest posting a new question accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. As you said. Highlighting the sentences is better option. It's fine for me. I'll Highlight the sentences. But I need a small help from you. Could you please tell me how you do that. I don't know much about UtterancesProgress listener. It will be very Helpful.

Comment: You're welcome.  I can give that a try, but I think it would be more appropriate to accept this answer and then give it a try yourself, then ask a new, more precise question if and when you have problems.

Comment: Are you still working on this?  I edited the answer.  If you like this answer, please accept it (and others) thanks!

Comment: For onRangeStart(), I am facing an issue if the text that I am trying to speak has punctuations like full stop, question mark and exclamation mark. The issue happens if the text is a paragraph with multiple lines. onRangeStart() stops sending start, end and frame data once it encounters any of the above mentioned punctuations so the callbacks from onRangeStart() method are unreliable.

Comment: @NerdyBunz - thank you for the solution. It works, however what I observed that for very large text it starts slowly lagging behind and eventually stops highlighting text (although the audio continues). There are no exception in logs that i was able to point out for slowness. In one or two instance observed GC memory in logs. But not sure if that's because of this code. Have you observed such errors?

Answer (score 2):

**If you want to change paragraph color which is current speaking in TTS.**

> ***This code works in Google TTS, Samsung TTS and also other TTS engines***

First you have to implement **TextToSpeech.OnInitListener**
Like (*public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements TextToSpeech.OnInitListener*)

**This is all essential object and variable used in this code.**

```
private String sentance = "";
private String typingString = "";
private int paragraphCount = 0;
private HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
private ArrayList<String> stringArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
```

**In your activity onCrreat() method**

```
tts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
map = new HashMap<>();
map.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_UTTERANCE_ID, "UniqueID")
```

**Paste this method into your activity and call this method at the click of a button.**

```
private void newPlayMethod() {
    if (paragraphCount == 0) {
        stringArrayList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("Your Document texts".split("\n")));
    }
    try {
        SpannableString spannableString = new SpannableString(tvData.getText().toString());
        spannableString.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark)),
                0, tvData.getText().toString().length(), 33);
        spannableString.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent)),
                tvData.getText().toString().indexOf(stringArrayList.get(paragraphCount)),
                tvData.getText().toString().indexOf(stringArrayList.get(paragraphCount)) +
                        stringArrayList.get(paragraphCount).length(),
                33);

        tts.speak(stringArrayList.get(paragraphCount), TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, map);

        tvData.setText(spannableString);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Put below code into **@Override onInit** method.

```
 tts.setOnUtteranceProgressListener(new UtteranceProgressListener() {

        @Override
        public void onStart(String utteranceId) {
            Log.i("TTS", "utterance started");
        }

        @Override
        public void onDone(String utteranceId) {
            if (stringArrayList.size() != paragraphCount) {
                paragraphCount++;
                newPlayMethod();
            } else {
                paragraphCount = 0;
            }
            Log.i("TTS", "utterance done");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(String utteranceId) {
            Log.i("TTS", "utterance error");
        }

    });
```