# bug in highlighting words that are spoken by text-to-speech reader in android

Tags: java, android, text-to-speech, java-threads

I am not getting desired output .
My code prints the whole string afterwards as a whole rather than printing in parts that are spoken by the android  text to speech reader.
please help me clarify my error. And please reply soon or anyone have any github repo regarding it then please give the link.I am feeling very demotivated with such situations occuring too often to me in  android studio.

here is my MainActivity.java code  from android studio....

```
    package com.example.ttsreader;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Html;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Locale;

import static android.widget.Toast.*;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private TextToSpeech textToSpeech;
    private Button btn;
    private EditText editText;
    private TextView txtView;
    String x="";
    String sss;

    private static final String TAG = "UpdateUI";

    private Handler handler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            Bundle b = msg.getData();
            String key = b.getString("timeKey");
            tv.setText(key);
        }
    };

    private Runnable separateThread = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            updateUI();
        }

    };

    private TextView tv;


    private String getTime() {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        DateFormat formatTime = DateFormat.getTimeInstance();
        return formatTime.format(calendar.getTime());
    }

    private void updateUI(){
        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + 5 * 1000;
        txtView.setText(x);
    }


    String ss;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
        txtView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et);
        textToSpeech = new TextToSpeech(getApplicationContext(), new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInit(int status) {
                if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
                    int ttsLang = textToSpeech.setLanguage(Locale.UK);

                    if (ttsLang == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA
                            || ttsLang == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
                        Log.e("TTS", "The Language is not supported!");
                    } else {
                        Log.i("TTS", "Language Supported.");
                    }
                    Log.i("TTS", "Initialization success.");
                } else {
                    makeText(getApplicationContext(), "TTS Initialization failed!", LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                String data = editText.getText().toString();

                try{
                    String arr[]=data.split("\\s");

                       for(final String s:arr)
                       {
                           x+=" ";
                           x+=s;
                           sss=s;
                           Thread t = new Thread(separateThread);
                           int speechStatus = textToSpeech.speak(sss, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
                           if (speechStatus == TextToSpeech.ERROR) {

                           }
                           t.start();
                           Thread.sleep(300);
                          /* txtView.setText(x);
                           int speechStatus = textToSpeech.speak(s, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
                           if (speechStatus == TextToSpeech.ERROR) {


                           }*/

                       }
                  }
                catch(Exception e)
                {

                }
            }

        });

    }

   /* public void dospeak(final String s,String data)
    {
        String newString = data.replaceAll(s, "<font color='red'>"+s+"</font>");
        ss=newString;
        //extView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);



    }
*/
}
```

Comment: Are you still working on this?  You may find this answer helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59488998/highlighting-the-text-while-speech-is-progressing