# Why my onRangeStart() method of text to speech is not executing?

Tags: android, text-to-speech

I am working on a text to speech application, text to speech is working fine but now I want to highlight each word while it is being spoken by the speech to text engine.

However, I have overridden onRangeStart() method, but actually, **it is not executing in my device(API-25) and below.**

Text to Speech is working fine in all devices but the text is highlighted (while TTS processing) only in 26+ API devices. Why this is happing and how to make this functionality backwards compatible?
here is my code.

**Implemented OnInitListener()**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements TextToSpeech.OnInitListener {...
```

**Here is onInit(){...}

```
 @Override
public void onInit(int i) {
    if (i == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
        int result = mTTS.setLanguage(Locale.ENGLISH);

        if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
            Log.e("TTS", "Language not supported");
        } else {
            mButtonSpeak.setEnabled(true);
        }
    } else {
        Log.e("TTS", "Initialization failed");
    }
    mTTS.setOnUtteranceProgressListener(new UtteranceProgressListener() {
        @Override
        public void onStart(String s) { Log.d("TTS", "onStart: "+s); }

        @Override
        public void onDone(String s) { Log.d("TTS", "onDone: "); }

        @Override
        public void onError(String s) { Log.d("TTS", "onError: "); }


        @Override
        public void onRangeStart(String utteranceId, final int start, final int end, int frame) {
            super.onRangeStart(utteranceId, start, end, frame);
            Log.d(TAG, "onRangeStart: ");
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Spannable coloredText = new SpannableString(mTextParagraph.getText());
                    coloredText.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.GREEN),
                            start,
                            end,
                            Spanned.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
                    mTextParagraph.setText(coloredText);
                    Log.d(TAG, "Color: ");
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: onRangeStart should be part of a UtteranceProgressListener, not OnInitListener.  see this other answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59488998/highlighting-the-text-while-speech-is-progressing

Comment: ye it is, I just call that anonymously, its a part of UtteranceProgressListener() and there are other three methods I have overridden already, actually I just cut the code because  StackOverflow was showing too much code while posting this problem, and I am also following the same link as you mentioned here in the comment. BTW thanks a lot for giving me your precious time buddy.

Comment: Stackoverflow was showing too much code?  Is the code secret?  This question doesn't show enough code for anyone to help you.

Comment: @NerdyBunz Bro I have changed the code now please have a look on it and guide me accordingly. a big sorry for late responding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because onRangeStart was [added in API 26](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/UtteranceProgressListener#onRangeStart(java.lang.String,%20int,%20int,%20int)).  Therefore, unfortunately, it doesn't work on API 25.

Comment: thanks for your reply pal, but now I have another query, so may I ask you here or should I have to post it into a separate Question?  however, the query is related to this onRangeStart Method. ok let me explain actually I m getting the proper output as I want, but when I m increasing the speech rate = 2.0 and taking a long paragraph(300 char) then this onStartRange method is not highlighting the last few words and I think this happening because time mismatch, now I wanna ask you how to resolve this issue, is there any way to solve it or it is normal thing. thanks a loat buddy

Comment: moreover, onRangeStart() stoped its working in the middle of the Text, however, TTS processed the whole text into speech.

Comment: I don't know the answer to that...  I would post another separate question and meanwhile try using log statements (inside onRangeStart) to verify it's not some kind of UI problem.  It could also be that the speech engine just isn't implementing onRangeStart properly.

Comment: @TayyabHusain: Were you able to resolve the issue of onRangeStart() getting stopped in the middle? I too am experiencing something similar where I stop getting onRangeStart() events after I encounter a punctuation like full stop, question mark or exclamation mark.

Comment: @GauravSaluja no man I didn't find that solution, actually mine was a little bit different, as when I am increasing the speed of speech then only I was facing that problem, it was not synching to the words being spoken by the speech reader.